# Passing a polymorphic model to a Laravel artisan command construct

Tags: laravel, polymorphic-associations, laravel-artisan

When passing a model to a Laravel Artisan console command using an argument, what is the best way to do this with a polymorphic model (ie. the argument can reference an instance of a `Post`, `Comment` or `Video`)?

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\User;
use App\Post;
use App\Comment;
use App\Video;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class CreateItem extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'create:item {item}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Add an item';

    protected $item;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     */
    public function __construct(VariousModels $item)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->item = $item;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        switch(true){
          case $this->item is instanceof App\Comment:
          break;
          case $this->item is instanceof App\Video:
          break;
          case $this->item is instanceof App\Post:
          break;
          ...
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: As in how would you type hint the various models?

Comment: Yes, I suppose. I don't think you can just line them all up like this `__construct(Post Video Comment $item)` - I get errors if I do it that way, and I dont think you can just pass the `$item` variable to the construct without a dependency injection.

Comment: I was thinking if you're wanting to have a bit of validation you could always use an interface to make sure that the correct models are being passed, however, I doubt you'll be able to do it if you're wanting dependency injection.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Thanks for your help. Can't seem to find a clean way to do this.